# could not find compatible versions for gem "multi_json":

Tags: ruby-on-rails, salesforce

I try to run the server but this result  always appear to me

```
could not find compatible versions for gem "multi_json":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 3.2.6) ruby depends on
      multi_json (~> 1.0) ruby
```

I have rails 3.2.6 
I try to use bundle update but the same result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `gem "multi_json"` in Gemfile

delete the Gemfile.lock file

And then run `bundle install`

This helped me to overcome the above error.

Answer (score 0):

Find the lowest compatible version for multi_json in your bundle. In my case it was 1.3.0 so I added the following to my Gemfile

`gem "multi_json", "~> 1.3.0"`

Then run

`bundle update multi_json`

This will unlock multi_json from the conflicting version and install your bundle according to the lowest compatible version.